# Report template for thesis

Tags: numbering, titles, geometry, thesis, report

I am writing my thesis using the `report` template. 
I want to start counting the pages from the first chapter and leave all the presentation pages with no page numbering.

I also need to reduce the size of my titles 
Chapter:14pt
Sections:12pt
Subsections:12pt

I am using this but it isn't working:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{14}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{12}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}}
```

Also I need to have this space on each page:

```
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

But on the beginning of each chapter the top space is much longer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am no `titlesec` expert, but `\fontsize` should have a 2nd argument and normally followed by `\selectfont`, but the later might been added by the `titlesec` setup automatically. In addition, the chapter header has some topskip, i.e. 50 pt (default) above the chapter title

Comment: Please note, that pointsizes are sometimes weird if compared to Word etc.